# Carrierwave doesn't work on other PC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I used carrierwave to upload images on the website and update my code to my github. After other checkout from my github, they cannot upload images.(The code is exactly same).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is: **No such file or directory - Identify**

Make sure that ImageMagick is installed on the system.

The command `which convert` or `which identify` should give you a path outpout of where Imagemagick is installed (if ImageMagick is installed correctly).

Comment: then ImageMagick is not installed or not installed correctly on the system. You need to install it.

Comment: Ok, I got it...How can I include ImageMagick in the code So others don't need to install ImageMagick?

Comment: I don't know if thats possible, as ImageMagick needs to be installed on the Operating System